# How to make windows Apache use all cpu cores?

Tags: windows, multithreading, apache, wamp

I've got Windows machine with i7 processor, but only one httpd process, which can top only one core. How to tell Apache to spawn multiple processes and use all cores?

Thanks

Comment: How is it configured? I think you want it running in MPM mode using mpm_winnt.

Comment: mpm_winnt is running, it's mostly defautl wamp. how do I check how it's configured?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a httpd.conf or apache2.conf file somewhere in the application folder (just search for all the `.conf` files in that folder with the file manager). If it is not there, then it might be in the system folder, but I highly doubt it.

This file is the main configuration one. Inside, you should try to find the *directives* related to mpm_winnt as listed in the right panel of the [documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_winnt.html) of mpm_winnt. `ThreadLimit` and `ThreadPerChild` seems to be important in that regard.

If you don't find these settings in your configuration files, then they should have default values which don't prevent multithreading to occur. The [documentation for the Mpm worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html) module indicates some other possibilities:

- `MaxClients`
- `ServerLimit`
- `MaxRequestsPerChild`

All these settings work together and misconfiguring one of them might break parallelism.

The documentation gives an example of a typical setup which you could give a try to.

Comment: My httpd.conf (apache2 running on windows) doesn't have ThreadLimit or ThreadPerChild.